# In the array " a " of size ‘n’ of integers find the longest subsequence of numbers such that each

Tags: c

In the array " a " of size ‘n’ of integers find the longest subsequence of numbers such that each successive element of the subsequence would be divided completely by the previous one. C

Comment: Input 1, 2, 4, 8, 0, 2, 5, 15 Output 1 2 4 8 0

Answer (score 0):

If an integer `a` is divisible by another integer `b`, their modulo is 0. That is `a % b == 0`.

So given a sequence:

```
int longest_sequence(unsigned int* seq, unsigned int length) {
  // Check non-NULL pointer, etc.

  for (unsigned int i = 1; i < length; ++i) {
    if (seq[i] == 0 || seq[i] % seq[i-1] != 0) { // Not divisible by previous
      return i; // Return length
    }
  }
  return length; // all the sequence matches
}
```